# Save a csv file using asksaveasfilename in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a *tkinter* application where we are supposed to have an entry that can be used to save a csv file using the `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` module.

So far what I achieved shown below, but it needs to be improved. Please help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox, filedialog
import pandas as pd

win = tk.Tk()
win.title('Save')
win.geometry('200x150')


global save_status
save_status = False

def save_file(data, status):    
    global save_status
    save_status = status 

    if save_status:
         file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".csv",
                                            filetypes=[("csv file", ".csv")],
                                            )
         data.to_csv(file_path, sep = ";", index = False, decimal = ",")

    # wigets
    save_var = tk.BooleanVar(value = False) 
    save_check= ttk.Checkbutton(win, text = "Save Data", 
                 variable = save_var, onvalue = True, offvalue = False, width = 10)
    save_check.pack(side = "left", padx = 15, pady = 10)
    
    #  data 
    df = pd.DataFrame({"Age": [23, 35, 75], 
                      "Salary": [2000, 2500, 4000]})

    # save file according to status of checkbox
    save_file(df, save_var.get())

    win.mainloop()
```

**Output** shown in graph below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What code have you written for this so far?

Comment: What is your question?  How to save a csv file? or how to use the asktosavefile function?

Comment: You're still missing a clear question: what is the problem and/or what are you trying to improve?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to ask for file name:

```
asksaveasfilename(filetypes = [('All tyes(*.*)', '*.*'),("csv file(*.csv)","*.csv")], defaultextension = [('All tyes(*.*)', '*.*'),("csv file(*.csv)","*.csv")])
```

You can open it when button is clicked by doing this:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter import *

base = Tk()

def SaveFile():
   data = [('All tyes(*.*)', '*.*'),("csv file(*.csv)","*.csv")]
   file = asksaveasfilename(filetypes = data, defaultextension = data)
   # file will have file name provided by user.
   # Now we can use this file name to save file.
   with open(file,"w") as f:
      f.write(<data you want to save>)

save_btn = Button(base, text = 'Click to save file ', command = SaveFile)
save_btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 20,padx = 50)

base.mainloop()
```

In `filetypes` and `defaultextension` you have to provide `list of tuple`, inside tuple you first element should be what user see and second element is the actual extension.

For more/detail information you can read [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/dialog.html).

**Twist**: Actually you may use [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module itself, if you are trying to save csv files. There are other libraries also but it is straightforward and easy to use so, I am suggesting it.
Here's the basic example:

```
import csv
with open('<file name.csv>', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

Comment: @sandyspace  you can try this out, if this solved your problem then don't forget to mark this as accepted answer, and additionally if any queries then ask in comment.

Comment: This gets a file name but doesn't actually save anything.  But the OP was unclear about the problem.

Comment: @RufusVS Yeah! OP is also unclear and, now I am confused but I edited answer, check it.

Comment: Better, but you might want to suggest the `csv` module, if he wants to write a csv file.

Comment: I have added suggestion about `csv` and provided some basic example.

Comment: Looks great!  Whatever he is asking, you probably have it covered.